# Multiple Google Invisible reCaptcha returning "Unable to post message to https://www.google.com" after first

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have a site that allows people to record the status of a handful of things roughly every 30 minutes via a series of voting buttons (3 buttons for each thing for the various statuses, 10 - 15 things). I'm trying to implement Google's Invisible reCaptcha to prevent some bot spam I was receiving.

I've managed to get the Invisible reCaptcha implemented and it works fine for the first vote but on any subsequent votes on the same page I get the following error from the console

```
[Error] Unable to post message to https://www.google.com. Recipient has origin https://example.com.

    postMessage
    l (recaptcha__en.js:210:171)
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function) (recaptcha__en.js:54:445)
    Lf (recaptcha__en.js:58:203)
    Gf (recaptcha__en.js:58:91)
    F (recaptcha__en.js:57:201)
    nf (recaptcha__en.js:51:1190)
    promiseReactionJob
```

My implementation is as follows.

This is the function the is called when a user presses a button. I pass it some variables which are then used later to actually log the votes, although for testing I'm just having it print them to the console. That `console.log` command in the callback will be replaced with a call to the function that actually logs the votes later.

```
function buttonPress(typeVote, value, e, thing) {

  //Create a unique name for the captcha's div 
  var captchaName = value + "captcha";

  //e is a reference to the div holding the things' button
  //so we add the captcha's div after it
  $($(e).parent()).after("<div id='" + captchaName + "'></div>");

  //Render the captcha
  grecaptcha.render(captchaName, {
              sitekey: 'SITE_KEY_HERE', size: 'invisible',
              callback: function(token) {

                            //This will be replaced with a call to the function
                            //that actually logs the votes with an AJAX call.
                            console.log("TOKEN: " + token + "THING: " + thing + "Vote: " + typeVote);

                            //Remove the captcha div so we can recreate if user 
                            //votes again
                            $(value + 'captcha').remove();

                          }});
  //Test the user
  grecaptcha.execute();

  //By default the captcha badge is appended to the div the captcha
  //is contained in. That is hiding it behind content so move it to 
  //the end of the body tag so it's visible
  $('body').append($('.grecaptcha-badge'));
}
```

Then at the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>` tag I import the Google reCaptcha library.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer ></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Google talks about the optional widget ID that you can use to call the execute or reset function they are not actually referring to the ID you assign to the div where the widget is created but instead a unique ID that is returned by the render function.

You have to assign that function to a variable and then use that variable as a passed parameter to the execute or reset function.

```
function buttonPress(typeVote, value, e, thing) {

  //Create a unique name for the captcha's div 
  var captchaName = value + "captcha";

  //e is a reference to the div holding the things' button
  //so we add the captcha's div after it
  $($(e).parent()).after("<div id='" + captchaName + "'></div>");

  //Render the captcha
  var widgetReference = grecaptcha.render(captchaName, {
              sitekey: 'SITE_KEY_HERE', size: 'invisible',
              callback: function(token) {

                            //This will be replaced with a call to the function
                            //that actually logs the votes with an AJAX call.
                            console.log("TOKEN: " + token + "THING: " + thing + "Vote: " + typeVote);

                            //Remove the captcha div so we can recreate if user 
                            //votes again
                            grecaptcha.reset(widgetReference);
                            $(value + 'captcha').remove();

                          }});
  //Test the user
  grecaptcha.execute(widgetReference);

  //By default the captcha badge is appended to the div the captcha
  //is contained in. That is hiding it behind content so move it to 
  //the end of the body tag so it's visible
  $('body').append($('.grecaptcha-badge'));
}
```